# cloud9 terminal won't let me exit and is stuck

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, cloud9-ide

I'm on cloud9 and somehow i can't exit my terminal. I don't know how to explain this, but it appears my terminal is permanently on ubuntu@deucex-deucex-4861145:~/workspace$ 
No matter what I do, I cannot leave it. If I close the terminal and reopen it, it goes back to ubuntu@deucex-deucex-4861145:~/workspace$ 
If I try cd .. it goes to ubuntu@deucex-deucex-4861145:~$ 
control c doesn't even work. What can I do to get out?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to see if I understand the problem correctly. Is the issue that the prompt of your terminal, which is `ubuntu@deucex-deucex-4861145`, is not what you expected it to be?
[Here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) is a link for configuring the prompt of your bash terminal.

On a default Cloud9 workspace, the output of `echo $PS1` is the following:
`\[\033[01;32m\]${C9_USER}@${C9_PROJECT}\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$(__git_ps1 " (%s)") $`

Which is how the prompt is configured.